# Puppeteer: Timeout after button click

Tags: puppeteer

I'm trying to submit a login form, but all I get is a timeout after 30 seconds.

My code is rather simple and I can't find anything wrong:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const creds = {
    user: "1234",
    password: "1234"
};

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({width: 1280, height: 800});
  await page.goto('https://shop2.idena.de/NewShop/');
  await page.type('input[name="FORM_LOGIN"]', creds.user);
  await page.type('input[name="FORM_PASSWD"]', creds.password);

  await Promise.all([
    page.click('button[name="FORM_TYPE"]'),
    page.waitForNavigation()
  ]);

  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png', fullPage: true});
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Any ideas what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of the promises a bit, it could be possible, the navigation happens super fast and the waitForNavigation is just waiting for nothing. Or maybe your website loads very slow after clicking the login button.

```js
await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation({timeout: 60000}),
    page.click('button[name="FORM_TYPE"]'),
]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work either, I don't really understand why. Can also be tested with wrong login data.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: I'm updating my answer since more infomration has been provided in the original question.

The problem is that there's a dialog you need to confirm/dismiss:

[image]

Perhaps you didn't see it because the script was too fast. I recommend debugging puppeteer scripts with headless set to false and slowMo to some number greater than 0:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, slowMo: 200 });
```

Then you need to get rid of the dialog:

```js
page.on('dialog', async (dialog) => {    
    await dialog.accept();
});
```

The whole script that now passes:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const creds = {
    user: "1234",
    password: "1234"
};

(async () => {  

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({width: 1280, height: 800});
    await page.goto('https://shop2.idena.de/NewShop/');
    await page.type('input[name="FORM_LOGIN"]', creds.user);
    await page.type('input[name="FORM_PASSWD"]', creds.password);

    page.on('dialog', async (dialog) => {    
        await dialog.accept();
    });

    await Promise.all([
        page.click('button[name="FORM_TYPE"]'),
        page.waitForNavigation()
    ]);

    await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png', fullPage: true});
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work either. I have extended the script above, it is now 100% complete to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DOB: I updated my answer based on your updated question with the actual link to the site. I think it should now work as expected, please check it as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I use your example with headful option, I get this dialog that prevents the page from loading:

[image]

So this addition can help (not sure if some dialog emerges with correct credentials):

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const creds = {
    user: "1234",
    password: "1234"
};

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({width: 1280, height: 800});
  await page.goto('https://shop2.idena.de/NewShop/');
  await page.type('input[name="FORM_LOGIN"]', creds.user);
  await page.type('input[name="FORM_PASSWD"]', creds.password);

  page.on('dialog', async dialog => {
    console.log(dialog.message());
    await dialog.accept();
  });

  await Promise.all([
    page.click('button[name="FORM_TYPE"]'),
    page.waitForNavigation()
  ]);

  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png', fullPage: true});
  await browser.close();
})();
```